# How does the lightsaber rifle work (in universe)?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, lightsaber

From what limited things I’ve seen on the internet, the lightsaber rifle consumes lightsabers as ammunition. I don’t know exactly which comics it’s in, but I know Jocasta Nu uses it against Vader, but her lightsaber is drained of power before Vader is hit. Is there any sources that explain how this weapon works, and/or how it drains a kyber crystal in a lightsaber.

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lightsaber_rifle

Comment: I believe the general answer is "It's not explained" although I'd be happy to have someone find more data.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, that’s a bother. Would be fun to see how it drains the lightsaber though.

Comment: @RYANLANDELS: My gut feeling is that it's probably something in between the crystal eventually channeling too much power, or that [lightsabers can run out of "batteries"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8515/did-any-lightsaber-ever-run-out-of-power) and require recharging.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - That was my thought, that the lack of power isn't because the crystal is somehow drained, but just that the power cells in the hilt are drained